# Identity info missing when serializing ids with the Jackson JSON parser

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am currently trying to serialize an object tree and deserialize it afterwards, so that all references remain the same. The problem is, that the fields holding those references are of type Object. The following code snippet

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Root r = new Root();
        Element e = new Element();
        e.s = "test";
        r.o1 = e;
        r.o2 = e;

        ObjectMapper ma = new ObjectMapper();
        ma.addMixInAnnotations(Object.class, Mixin.class);

        String json = ma.writeValueAsString(r);
        System.out.println(json);

        Root r2 = ma.readValue(json, Root.class);
        System.out.println(r2.o1.getClass());
        System.out.println(r2.o2.getClass());
        System.out.println(r2.o1 == r2.o2);
    }



    public static class Root {

        public Object o1;

        public Object o2;

    }

    public static class Element {

        public String s;

    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
    public static class Mixin {

    }

}
```

results in the following output:

```
{"@class":"Main$Root","@id":1,"o1":{"@class":"Main$Element","@id":2,"s":"test"},"o2":2}
Main$Element
java.lang.Integer
false
```

The first occurence of 'Element' is deserialized correctly, as it has the type information attached to it. The second one however is not, as the type information is not added when only the id is serialized. The id is deserialized as an Integer, because the parser does not recognize it as an id, because the field is of type 'Object'.

So the question is: Is there a way to tell Jackson to attach type information even when writing only the id, so that the deserialized 'Elements' are the same?

EDIT: The type must be Object, since in my use case the content can be practically anything, even classes I have no control of. So the main issue is how to inculde the type information in the reference itself.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try changing your mixin registration to your target types and remove the `Object.class` registration. `ma.addMixInAnnotations(Root.class, Mixin.class);` and `ma.addMixInAnnotations(Element.class, Mixin.class);`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Now even the first element is deserialized wrong.
`{"@class":"Main$Root","@id":1,"o1":{"@id":2,"s":"test"},"o2":2}
java.util.LinkedHashMap
java.lang.Integer
false`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've figured this out.

When using `@JsonTypeInfo`, Jackson tries to shorthand objects when they are the **SAME** object as an object that's already been serialized. In that case, instead of including the data, it only includes a reference to the previously serialized object. This makes sense.

For some reason, however, using `Object` in your `Root' object doesn't carry the identity and things break from there. If you create a dummy interface, use that as your base type, drop the MixIn on it and have`Element` implement it, it all works out.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Root r = new Root();

    Element e = new Element();
    e.s = "test1";
    r.o1 = e;
    r.o2 = e;

    ObjectMapper ma = new ObjectMapper();
    ma.addMixInAnnotations(Root.class, Mixin.class);
    ma.addMixInAnnotations(Base.class, Mixin.class);

    String json = ma.writeValueAsString(r);
    System.out.println(json);

    Root r2 = ma.readValue(json, Root.class);
    System.out.println(r2.o1.getClass());
    System.out.println(r2.o2.getClass());
    System.out.println(r2.o1 == r2.o2);
}

public static class Root {
    public Base o1;
    public Base o2;
}

public interface Base {
}

public static class Element implements Base {
    public String s;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public static class Mixin {

}
```

This gets the following output:

```
{"@class":"Main$Root","@id":1,"o1":{"@class":"Main$Element","@id":2,"s":"test1"},"o2":2}
class Main$Element
class Main$Element
true
```

This testing was done with Jackson 2.3.3

Comment: I think this works, because the type of the id (an integer in this case) is not assignable to the type of the variable (the `Base` interface). If the variable type is `Object`, the deserializer CAN assign the integer to the variable, so he does it. However, I am afraid that the type must be `Object`, since in my use case the content can be practically anything, even classes I have no control of. So the main issue is how to inculde the type information in the reference itself. Sorry I didn't mention that in the question, updated accordingly.